# how to use right to left icons in semantic-ui accordion?

Tags: user-interface, icons, accordion, semantic-ui, user-experience

I want to use "semantic-ui" accordion with "rtl" icon in default accordion's icons looks like > and i want my accordions icons looks like this <

please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the icon class that you are using to achieve your requirement.

I have used "angle left icon" for rtl. There are many more icon to show rtl, here is the [link](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html) that contains list of supported icon by default in semantic.

```
<div class="ui styled accordion">
   <div class=" title">
      <i class="angle left icon"></i>
      Title1
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Title Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: 
Make sure you are using icons from the correct version. Some of the [legacy](http://legacy.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon.html) version icons doesn't work with the latest semantic version.